# ARM Template Web App Authentication Settings not working

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, azure-resource-manager

I am working on setting up my site authentication settings to use the AAD provider.  Most of the template is respected. However, the `unauthenticatedClientAction` and `allowedAudiences` is not being properly assigned. I observe 'allow anonymous' and no 'allowed audiences' being assigned.

> Please note that I was working with the ARM Template API [2018-02-01](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/2018-02-01/sites/config-authsettings). This problem may still exist due to the documentation, if you provide an answer, please note the ARM Template version it addresses.
>
> Additionally, create an issue for the ARM documentation team to correct any issues.

Here is my template segment for these settings. It is nested under resources in my website template.

root > Microsoft.Web/Site > Resources

```
{
    "type": "config",
    "name": "web",
    "apiVersion": "2016-08-01",
    "location": "[parameters('app-location')]",
    "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', variables('web-site-name'))]"
    ],
    "properties": {
        "siteAuthEnabled": true,
        "siteAuthSettings": {
            "enabled": true,
            "unauthenticatedClientAction": "RedirectToLoginPage",
            "tokenStoreEnabled": true,
            "defaultProvider": "AzureActiveDirectory",
            "clientId": "[parameters('web-aad-client-id')]",
            "issuer": "[concat('https://sts.windows.net/', parameters('web-aad-tenant'))]",
            "allowedAudiences": [
                "[concat('https://', variables('web-site-name'), '.azurewebsites.net')]"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

- Template Validates
- Deployment does not output any errors

Issues:

1. `unauthenticatedClientAction` is assigned allow anonymous not RedirectToLoginPage
2. `allowedAudiences` is not assigned any sites

What could be causing these issues? What could I have missed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I got my answer after working with the fine people at Azure Support.

> Please note that this solution targets API [2018-02-01](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/2018-02-01/sites/config-authsettings) which was the current version at the time of this post.

This sub-resource is no longer a valid solution, while the endpoint may still recognize some of its fields, this is deprecated.

The new solution is to add the `siteAuthSettings` object to the main 'Microsoft.Web/site' properties and the `siteAuthEnabled` is no longer needed as `siteAuthSettings.enable` duplicates this functionality.

Updated ARM Template (removed other settings for brevity)

```
{
    "name": "[variables('app-service-name')]",
    "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
    "location": "[parameters('app-location')]",
    "apiVersion": "2016-08-01",
    "dependsOn": [
        "[variables('app-plan-name')]"
    ],
    "properties": {
        //... other app service settings
        "siteAuthSettings": {
            "enabled": true,
            "unauthenticatedClientAction": "RedirectToLoginPage",
            "tokenStoreEnabled": true,
            "defaultProvider": "AzureActiveDirectory",
            "clientId": "[parameters('web-aad-client-id')]",
            "issuer": "[concat('https://sts.windows.net/', parameters('web-aad-tenant'))]",
            "allowedAudiences": [
                "[concat('https://', variables('web-site-name'), '.azurewebsites.net')]"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was having the same issue, the current documentation is still unclear about this. Part of my settings where applied others not. Putting it directly in the wep app properties worked for me but don't forget to put it in a "siteConfig" entry.

Comment: "sub-resource is no longer a valid solution, this is deprecated." Is this documented anywhere now? The latest API document version has no notes of deprecating Microsoft.Web/sites/config https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/2018-11-01/sites/config-authsettings

Comment: @MartinThøgersen Yes. This was written back in February. Please note that at that time this was the specifications: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/2018-02-01/sites/config-authsettings There are now new specifics for this scenario.

Answer (score 3):

As suggested by @Michael, the `siteAuthSettings` object must be added to the `siteConfig` object, not just under the root `properties` object.

```
{
    "apiVersion": "2019-08-01",
    "name": "[variables('webAppName')]",
    "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
    "kind": "app",
    "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
    "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', variables('appServiceName'))]"
    ],
    "properties": {
        ...
        "siteConfig": {
            "siteAuthSettings": {
                "enabled": true,
                "unauthenticatedClientAction": "RedirectToLoginPage",
                "tokenStoreEnabled": true,
                "defaultProvider": "AzureActiveDirectory",
                "clientId": "[parameters('clientId')]",
                "issuer": "[concat('https://sts.windows.net/', parameters('tenantId'), '/')]"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As this question was based on the version I noted in my answer, can you please note out what version this targets. The `apiVersion` field denotes only for the `type` of node and can be shared across ARM Template API versions. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The other solutions given only apply when using the classic authentication experience (*Authentication (Classic))*. If you would like to use the new authentication experience, use below configuration:

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "resources": [
    {
      "apiVersion": "2019-08-01",
      "name": "[variables('webAppName')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
      "kind": "app",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "resources": [
        {
          "type": "config",
          "apiVersion": "2020-12-01",
          "name": "authsettingsV2",
          "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
          "dependsOn": [
            "[concat('Microsoft.Web/sites/', variables('webAppName'))]"
          ],
          "properties": {
            "platform": {
              "enabled": true,
              "runtimeVersion": "~1"
            },
            "identityProviders": {
              "azureActiveDirectory": {
                "isAutoProvisioned": false,
                "registration": {
                  "clientId": "[parameters('clientId')]",
                  "clientSecret": "[variables('clientSecret')]",
                  "openIdIssuer": "[concat('https://sts.windows.net/', parameters('tenantId'), '/v2.0')]"
                },
                "validation": {
                  "allowedAudiences": [
                    "https://management.core.windows.net/"
                  ]
                }
              }
            },
            "login": {
              "routes": {},
              "tokenStore": {
                "enabled": true,
                "tokenRefreshExtensionHours": 72,
                "fileSystem": {},
                "azureBlobStorage": {}
              },
              "preserveUrlFragmentsForLogins": false,
              "allowedExternalRedirectUrls": [],
              "cookieExpiration": {
                "convention": "FixedTime",
                "timeToExpiration": "08:00:00"
              },
              "nonce": {
                "validateNonce": true,
                "nonceExpirationInterval": "00:05:00"
              }
            },
            "globalValidation": {
              "redirectToProvider": "azureactivedirectory",
              "unauthenticatedClientAction": "RedirectToLoginPage"
            },
            "httpSettings": {
              "requireHttps": true,
              "routes": {
                "apiPrefix": "/.auth"
              },
              "forwardProxy": {
                "convention": "NoProxy"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: This was written back in February of 2019. Please note that at that time this was the specifications: learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/… There are now new specifics for this scenario as you are pointing out.